# Replace a string in a textarea using selenium, "not reachable by keyboard"

Tags: python, selenium

I'd like to modify part of the text in a textarea with Selenium. The textarea seems almost as if it were read-only.

In this very simple example using a sample algo, it would be great to be able to change the stock id on this line:

```
context.aapl = sid(24)
```

... to something like:

```
context.aapl = sid(39840)
```

... which is the Tesla stock id. The variable name will no longer make sense, doesn't matter, just a start.

This Selenium code for me is able to open the sample with no login required.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

t = webdriver.Firefox()     # t stands for tab as in browser tab in my mind
t.implicitly_wait(10)
t.get('https://www.quantopian.com/algorithms/')
o = t.find_element_by_xpath("//body")       # o stands for object
o.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)                    # clearing the popup
o = t.find_element_by_link_text("Hello World Algorithm")
o.click()
''' for the fun of it if you want to run the backtest
o = t.find_element_by_xpath('//body')
o.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'b')
o.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
'''
print t.find_element_by_id('code-area').text
```

Here's the output from that

```
1
# Called once at the start of the simulation.
2
def initialize(context):
3
    # Reference to the AAPL security.
4
    context.aapl = sid(24)
5
6
    # Rebalance every day, one hour and a half after market open.
7
    schedule_function(my_rebalance,
8
        date_rules.every_day(),
9
        time_rules.market_open(hours=1, minutes=30))
10
11
# This function was scheduled to run once per day at 11AM ET.
12
def my_rebalance(context, data):
13
    14
    # Take a 100% long position in AAPL. Readjusts each day to
15
    # account for price fluctuations.
16
    if data.can_trade(context.aapl):
17
        order_target_percent(context.aapl, 1.00)
```

That id is 'code-area'. The content includes margin numbers which might be a problem. 
Next nested area is 'code-area-internal', seems the same. 
Followed by these two.

```
<div class='ide-container' id='ide-container'>
<textarea class='width_100pct' id='codebox'>
```

In trying to obtain the content of the algorithm with 'codebox', content doesn't appear to be present, just u'' ...

```
>>> p = t.find_element_by_id('codebox').text
>>> p
u''
```

Attempt to do CTRL-A on it results in this exception...

```
>>> o = t.find_element_by_id('codebox')
>>> o.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
```

**ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard**

If the text can be completely cut, then replace can done in Python and paste, that would be fine. 
I wouldn't expect Selenium to be able to find and replace text, just surprised it finds a visible area for user input to be off limits from interactivity.

That textarea does have its own Find, and hoping won't have to resort to trying to use it as a workaround.

*(The environment is an online IDE for stock market algorithms called Quantopian)*

This is the one other thing I tried, with no apparent effect:

```
>>> t.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", t.find_element_by_id("ide-container"), "_new_")
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Textarea has `style="display: none"` attribute which means that you cannot get its content with `text` property. In this case you can use:

```
p = t.find_element_by_id('codebox').get_attribute("textContent")
```

To set new value to code field you can use:

```
field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role="presentation"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent = 'New value';", field)
```

But note that initially each code line in code field displayed as separate `div` node with specific value and styles. So to make new value looks exactly as code (in the same formatting) you can prepare HTML sample e.g.

```
value = """<div style="position: relative;"><div class="CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper" style="left: -48px;"><div class="CodeMirror-linenumber CodeMirror-gutter-elt" style="left: 15px; width: 21px;">1</div></div><pre class=" CodeMirror-line " role="presentation"><span role="presentation" style="padding-right: 0.1px;"><span class="cm-comment"># Comment for new code.</span></span></pre></div>"""
```

and do

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];", field, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

The content of the algorithm with **codebox** which you are trying to extract is having the *style* attribute set to **display: none;**. So to extract the text you can use the following lines of code :

```
p = t.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ide-container']/textarea[@id='codebox']")
t.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", p)
print(t.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```